# R grep regular expression using elements in a vector

Tags: r, regex

Even at the risk of being this question labeled as duplicated, I am going to ask since all the related questions I have checked do not solve my problem...

I have a `labs` vector and I want to find the elements that are exact matches to 3 groups stored in a `groups` variable.

```
set.seed(1)
labs <- sample(c(rep('BC-89HX',3), rep('BC-89HX with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat',3), rep('Own SH',4)), 10)
labs
groups <- c('BC-89HX','BC-89HX with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat','Own SH')
```

I want to identify the "BC-89HX" group elements (not the "BC-89HX with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat" ones)

```
grep(groups[1], labs, val=TRUE, fixed=TRUE) #finds more elements than the ones I need
grep(paste(groups[1],"$",sep=""), labs, val=TRUE, fixed=TRUE) #does not work
grep(paste("\\b",groups[1],"\\b",sep=""), labs, val=TRUE, fixed=TRUE) #does not work
```

Any help?

Comment: The `does not work` is not clear.  In the first case of 'grep', I get 6 matches out of the 10 elements in 'labs'.  What is your expected output?

Comment: Only the "BC-89HX" exact group elements, not the "BC-89HX with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat" ones

Comment: Are you looking for `grep(paste0("^", groups[1], "$"), labs, val=TRUE)# 
[1] "BC-89HX" "BC-89HX" "BC-89HX"`  In that case you can use `==` as well `labs[labs == groups[1]]`

Comment: Yes exactly! `paste0`! I was trying `grep(paste(groups[1], "$"), labels(dend.obj), val=TRUE, fixed=TRUE)` cause `groups[1]` contains `-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to be make sure that "BC-89HX" is the only characters in the string and by `paste`ing `^` and `$` we identify the starting and end position

```
grep(paste0("^", groups[1], "$"), labs, value=TRUE) 
#[1] "BC-89HX" "BC-89HX" "BC-89HX"
```

In this case, we cannot use the `fixed = TRUE` as `^` and `$` are metacharacters which imply the start and end location.  If we do `fixed = TRUE`, it will parse it as literal characters which the 'labs' doesn't have

Another option is to use `==` or `%in%` as we are comparing fixed strings instead of matching substring in a string

```
labs[labs == groups[1]]
#[1] "BC-89HX" "BC-89HX" "BC-89HX"

labs[labs == groups[2]]
#[1] "BC-89HX with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat" "BC-89HX with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat" "BC-89HX with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat"
```

#### Update

If we really wanted to use `grep` with `fixed = TRUE`, then one way is to `paste` in both the `pattern` and the strings with the same characters i.e.

```
labs[grep(paste0("^", groups[2], "$"), paste0("^", labs, "$"), fixed = TRUE) ]
#[1] "BC-89HX with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat" "BC-89HX with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat" "BC-89HX with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat"
labs[grep(paste0("^", groups[1], "$"), paste0("^", labs, "$"), fixed = TRUE) ]
#[1] "BC-89HX" "BC-89HX" "BC-89HX"
```

Comment: What about if I want to `grep` `group[2]`? Is there a unique solution that works for both cases?

Comment: @DaniCee  If you do the `==`, it should be working for both cases `labs[labs== groups[2]]`

Comment: Please check my new question, I don't know why this solution doesn't work there... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269338/r-grep-regular-expression-using-elements-in-a-vector-follow-up