# R grep regular expression using elements in a vector (FOLLOW UP)

Tags: r, regex

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229558/r-grep-regular-expression-using-elements-in-a-vector/49231001?noredirect=1#comment85465469_49231001), I have another example where I cannot use the accepted answer.

Again, I want to find each of the exact `group` elements in the `lab` vector...

```
labs <- c("Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN",
"Beijing -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN",
"Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Beijing -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Beijing -- T24 -- BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN",
"Zhangjiakou -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN",
"Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Zhangjiakou -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Zhangjiakou -- T0 -- BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN",
"Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN",
"Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Beijing -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN",
"Beijing -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN",
"Beijing -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Zhangjiakou -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN",
"Zhangjiakou -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN",
"Zhangjiakou -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Zhangjiakou -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN",
"Zhangjiakou -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN",
"Zhangjiakou -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC")
labs
groups <- c("BC-89 + CN", "BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC", "BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN")
groups
```

I try the following but it does not work...

```
grep(paste0(groups[1], "$"), labs, value=TRUE)
grep(paste0(groups[2], "$"), labs, value=TRUE)
grep(paste0(groups[3], "$"), labs, value=TRUE)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
lapply(groups, function(g)
  grep(gsub("\\+", "\\\\+", paste0(g, "$")), labs, value = TRUE))
# [[1]]
# [1] "Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN"     
# [2] "Beijing -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN"    
# [3] "Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN"     
# [4] "Zhangjiakou -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN" 
# [5] "Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN"     
# [6] "Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN"     
# [7] "Beijing -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN"    
# [8] "Beijing -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN"    
# [9] "Zhangjiakou -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN" 
# [10] "Zhangjiakou -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN" 
# [11] "Zhangjiakou -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN"
# [12] "Zhangjiakou -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"     
# [2] "Beijing -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"    
# [3] "Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"     
# [4] "Zhangjiakou -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC" 
# [5] "Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"     
# [6] "Beijing -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"    
# [7] "Zhangjiakou -- T0 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC" 
# [8] "Zhangjiakou -- T24 -- BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN"    
# [2] "Beijing -- T24 -- BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN"   
# [3] "Beijing -- T0 -- BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN"    
# [4] "Zhangjiakou -- T0 -- BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN"
```

The problem with your approach is that, e.g., `groups[1]` is `"BC-89 + CN"`, which contains `+`, having particular meaning in regular expressions. Given only this, adding `fixed = TRUE` in `grep` would fix the issue, but then `$` would lose its effect. So what I did is escaping `+` in the group names first.

Alternatively, and relating to your linked answer, you could do

```
lapply(groups, function(g)
  grep(paste0(g, "$"), paste0(labs, "$"), value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE))
```

Comment: I have another case in which I want to find the same groups in another vector, but cases where such group appears twice... in the same way, I apply the following replacing `$` with `{2}`, but it doesn't work... Should I open a new question? `grep(gsub("\\+", "\\\\+", paste0(groups[1], "{2}")), labs)`

Comment: @DaniCee, that doesn't work because it looks for two consecutive group names.. Like "Some text about group1group1 and so on". Try `grep(gsub("\\+", "\\\\+", paste0(g, ".+", g)), labs)`, if it doesn't work then a post a new question, everything about regex gets answered immediately anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this from the stringr package. The "coll" option implements "human readable collation rules" which helps you match things that look identical, but for some reason, R resists matching them at first:

```
> library(stringr)
> str_detect(labs,coll(groups))
 [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  
TRUE FALSE FALSE
[16]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

`+` is a special character in regex. You will need "\+" to escape the special character.

```
new_group <- gsub("\\+",replacement = "\\\\+",x =groups)
```

Also, "|" in grep serves like "or".

```
new_group1 <- paste0(new_group,collapse = "|")

grep(pattern = new_group1,x = labs,value = T)
```