# R grep regular expression to find exact elements in a vector twice

Tags: r, regex

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269338/r-grep-regular-expression-using-elements-in-a-vector-follow-up), I have another example where I cannot apply the accepted answer there.

This time, I want to find each of the EXACT `group` elements in the `labs` vector, occurring TWICE.

```
labs <- c("Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN",
"Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN",
"Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Beijing T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Beijing T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN",
"Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN",
"Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Beijing T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN --vs-- Beijing T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Beijing T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Beijing T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Beijing T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Beijing T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC",
"Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN",
"Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN")
labs
groups <- c("BC-89 + CN", "BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC", "BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN")
groups
```

This is my attempt, which is not working:

```
A <- grep(gsub("\\+", "\\\\+", paste0(groups[1], "{2}")), labs, value=TRUE) #only elements with exactly "BC-89 + CN" appearing twice
B <- grep(gsub("\\+", "\\\\+", paste0(groups[2], "{2}")), labs, value=TRUE) #only elements with exactly "BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC" appearing twice
C <- grep(gsub("\\+", "\\\\+", paste0(groups[3], "{2}")), labs, value=TRUE) #only elements with exactly "BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN" appearing twice
```

The desired output would be (note I want EXACT groups, so "BC-89 + CN" should not find "BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"):

```
> A
[1] "Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN"     
[2] "Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN"   
[3] "Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN"        
[4] "Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN"
> B
[1] "Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"     
[2] "Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"   
[3] "Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"        
[4] "Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"
> C
[1] "Beijing T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN"     
[2] "Beijing T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN"   
[3] "Beijing T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN --vs-- Beijing T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN"        
[4] "Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN"
```

Comment: what should be the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use (`paste0(group[1], ".*", group[1])` or `sprintf("(%s.*){2}", groups[1])`)

```
a <- grep(gsub("\\+", "\\\\+", sprintf("(%s.*){2}", groups[1])), labs)
b <- grep(gsub("\\+", "\\\\+", sprintf("(%s.*){2}", groups[2])), labs)
c <- grep(gsub("\\+", "\\\\+", sprintf("(%s.*){2}", groups[3])), labs)
```

Output:

```
> print(list(a, b, c))
# [[1]]
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  7  8  9 10 13 16 19 22
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  3  4  9 10
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  5  6 11 12
```

Take `groups[1]` (`"BC-89 + CN"`) as example, you are finding elements that contain `"BC-89 + CNBC-89 + CN"` only, but there can be other characters appears between the occurrences of your desired string.

---

**Edit**:

Since  "BC-89 + CN" groups should not contains "BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC", one more step is needed

```
a <- a[!a %in% b]
```

Output:

```
> print(a)
# [1]  1  2  7  8 13 16 19 22
```

---

**Edit 2:**

I notice that you may want to check if the 'group' string appears before and after' --vs-- ' (so twice), and think of another approach.

```
check_group <- function(ele, group) {
  x <- strsplit(ele, " --vs-- ")[[1]]
  group <- gsub("\\-", "\\\\-", group)
  group <- gsub("\\+", "\\\\+", group)
  group <- paste0(group, "$")
  if (grepl(group, x[[1]]) & grepl(group, x[[2]])) {
    return(ele)
  } else {
    return(NULL)
  }
}

remove_null <- function(x) {
  return(unlist(x[!sapply(x, is.null)]))
}


a1 <- remove_null(lapply(labs, check_group, groups[1]))
a2 <- remove_null(lapply(labs, check_group, groups[2]))
a3 <- remove_null(lapply(labs, check_group, groups[3]))
```

Output:

```
> print(list(a1, a2, a3))
# [[1]]
# [1] "Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN"      "Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN"   
# [3] "Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN"         "Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"     
# [2] "Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"   
# [3] "Beijing T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Beijing T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"        
# [4] "Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "Beijing T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN"     
# [2] "Beijing T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN"   
# [3] "Beijing T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN --vs-- Beijing T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN"        
# [4] "Zhangjiakou T0 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN --vs-- Zhangjiakou T24 - BC-89 with 2% Puricare + 5% Merquat + CN"
```

Comment: This is not the desired output, "BC-89 + CN" should find exact "BC-89 + CN" groups in `labs`, not "BC-89 + CN with 2% DD + 1.6% ZC" ones... Let me edit my question to reflect the desired outputs

Comment: @DaniCee I have edited my answer, does it fit your need?

Comment: The problem with this is that I might have many other groups, so there might be more group intersections. Plus it goes in a for loop, so each group is checked at a time